How can a Warlock learn Magic Missile?
My DM is starting a campaign using PHB, VGtM, TCoE, and XGtE as our sourcebooks. I'm playing as a Yuan-ti Warlock, while building for my character, I want to add the spell Magic Missile to my known spells but it isn't in the warlock spell list. Is there any way for me to do it instead of multiclassing into a sorcerer?

Hello there! Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and maybe visit the [help] to have any guidance on posting here. I put the dnd-5ed tag, since you mentioned a lot of manuals referring to this edition of Dungeons and Dragons.

I was initially thinking there'd be synergy between magic missile and Hex.  But no, it's not an attack roll so you don't even get one extra d6 of damage, let alone one per missile.  You want Scorching Ray if you want a beefier version of Eldritch Blast.  But Hexblade's Curse works with any damage roll, so the question becomes whether each missile is a separate damage roll.  Apparently yes: Would striking someone at 0 hit points with an entire Magic Missile spell automatically kill them?

If your table allows feats, take the Magic Initiate feat.
The Magic Initiate feat allows to learn a 1st level spell of your choice: in particular, one can take Magic Missile:

In addition, choose one 1st-level spell to learn from that same list. Using this feat, you can cast the spell once at its lowest level, and you must finish a long rest before you can cast it in this way again.

But unfortunately you can cast it only once per day: you cannot use your slots to cast it, per the following entry of the Sage Advice Compendium:

If you have spell slots, can you use them to cast the 1st-level spell you learn with the Magic Initiate feat?
Yes, but only if the class you pick for the feat is one of your classes. For example, if you pick sorcerer and you are a sorcerer, the Spellcasting feature for that class tells you that you can use your spell slots to cast the sorcerer spells you know, so you can use your spell slots to cast the 1st-level sorcerer spell you learn from Magic Initiate. Similarly, if you are a wizard and pick that class for the feat, you learn a 1st-level wizard spell, which you could add to your spellbook and subsequently prepare.
In short, you must follow your character’s normal spellcasting rules, which determine whether you can expend spell slots on the 1st-level spell you learn from Magic Initiate.

Search for a magic item.
One of these items, beside spell scrolls, is the wand of Magic Missile:

This wand has 7 charges. While holding it, you can use an action to expend 1 or more of its charges to cast the magic missile spell from it. For 1 charge, you cast the 1st-level version of the spell. You can increase the spell slot level by one for each additional charge you expend.

You can ask to your DM if they can make you find such item.
Work with your DM.
The DM has the final word: they can modify spell lists for any class, allowing hence warlocks to use Magic Missile spell. The DMG (page 287) provides some guidance in this sense:

Modifying a class’s spell list usually has little effect on a character’s power but can change the flavor of a class significantly. In your world, paladins might not swear their oaths to ideals, but instead swear fealty to powerful sorcerers. To capture this story concept, you could build a new paladin spell list with spells meant to protect their masters, drawn from the sorcerer or wizard lists. Suddenly, the paladin feels like a different class.
Be cautious when changing the warlock spell list. Since warlocks regain their spell slots after a short rest, they have the potential to use certain spells more times in a day than other classes do.

The DM should pay particular care in adding spell to Warlock list, as suggested in the last paragraph the quoted section, since they can cast spells at their highest level and regain spell slots with short rests.

Regarding your very last section, it may be worth mentioning the DMG’s guidance on modifying spell lists, which I quoted in this answer.

@ThomasMarkov Yep, good addendum! Thanks!

This is already a great answer, but since the question is specifically about magic missile, I think it’d be worth mentioning any specific issues with giving that spell to a warlock? Perhaps that it will always be cast at the highest level (up to 5), and can potentially be cast many more than four or five times a day, which is probably about what a wizard might do and given the higher level, much better than the wand can manage.

@GuybrushMcKenzie Yes, I thought was already implied in the last section of the quoted rules, but I emphasized it a little bit, following your suggestion.

@GuybrushMcKenzie: Also note the interaction with hexblade's curse, adding your proficiency bonus to each damage roll (i.e. to each dart).  So it's extra strong for a hexblade.

Some other feat options to consider are an Aberrant Dragonmark or Strixhaven Initiate.
Aberrant Dragonmark

You learn a cantrip of your choice from the sorcerer spell list. In
addition, choose a 1st-level spell from the sorcerer spell list. You
learn that spell and can cast it through your mark. Once you cast it,
you must finish a short or long rest before you can cast it again
through the mark. Constitution is your spellcasting ability for these
spells.

This would allow you access to the spell on a short rest, not quite a spell known but closer, and give more uses than 1x a day if you follow sage advice for the magic initiate feat mentioned in @Eddymage's answer.
Strixhaven Initiate
This may be harder to pull off from a lore perspective, but if you are in this setting or your GM is okay with re-theming, this seems to circumvent magic initiate restriction by clearly stating any spell slots may be used.

Choose one of Strixhaven's colleges: Lorehold, Prismari, Quandrix, Silverquill, or Witherbloom. You learn two cantrips and one 1st-level spell based on the college you choose, as specified in the Strixhaven Spells table.


You can cast the chosen 1st-level spell without a spell slot, and you must finish a long rest before you can cast it in this way again. You can also cast the spell using any spell slots you have.

(emphasis mine)
You would just need to choose one of the schools allowing you to pick from a sorcerer or wizard list.
